# Email not sent using Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-2

In my server email is sent if we use simple **[mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)** function but it's not sent by using the following codes of Codeigniter.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com'); 
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  
$this->email->send();
```

What is the issue behind it? What will be the solution for it? 
Thnx in advance.
Cheers

Result of print_debugger():

```
Unable to send email using PHP mail().  
Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.  
From: "My Site" Return-Path:  
Reply-To: "info@mysitedomain.com"  
X-Sender: info@mysitedomain.com  
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) 
Message-ID: <66751b444845099d@mysitedomain.com>  
Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 

=?utf-8?Q?test_email_sending.?= Test email message.
```

Comment: As said [in the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html), you should use email->print_debugger() to display the debugger information. We cannot help you until you add the result to your question.

Comment: Add it to your question, not as a comment. Your question as written right now is "I have a problem when I do something, help me". You don't say what's wrong, and where it blocks. [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you must enable PHP **Mail()** in your server to do mailing.

OR

you can try email using **SMTP**

Ref: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html